Index-2 subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Does $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ have any subgroups of index 2 besides $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? I suspect that the answer is “no,” however I am having some trouble proving that any subgroup of index 2 must consist solely of the matrices with determinant 1. Maybe I cannot prove it because I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

The quotient by an index two subgroup is abelian so any index two subgroup must contain the commutator subgroup. Can it be shown that $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is the commutator subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$? Also, an index two subgroup must contain $A^2$ for every $A\in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Yes, I now see an index-2 subgroup must contain the special linear group. Although I don’t see where the second fact about squares comes into play. Is it not conceivable that this index-2 subgroup contains some matrices of determinant -1, in addition to the determinant 1 matrices, somehow? Once I rule this out then I am done.

Yes there are three index $2$ subgroups in the group ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$.
It has the presentation
$$\langle p,s,u \mid p^2, s^2, (sp)^4, (upsp)^2,
   (ups)^3, (us)^2 \rangle,$$
where
$$p=\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right),\ s=\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right),\ u=\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$
(This comes from the paper T. Brady, Automatic structures on ${\rm Aut}(F_2)$, Arch. Math. 63, 97-102 (1994).)
From the presentation it is straightforward to calculate that its abelianization is ${\mathbb Z}/2 \times {\mathbb Z}/2$.
The derived group, of index $4$, is $\langle u^ 2, ps  u^{-1}, s  p  u^{-1}\rangle$, and the index $2$ subgroups are
(i) $\langle sp,u \rangle = {\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z}),$
(ii) $\langle s,up,u^{-1}p \rangle$, and
(iii) $\langle p,us,u^{-1}s,sps \rangle$.
